# subdata method in Swift doesn't seem to be doing as I want

Tags: swift

I have the following code in a playground (Swift 5)

```
import Foundation

let array : [UInt8] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
public extension Data {
    func uint32( offset:Int)-> UInt32{

        let range = offset..<(offset+4)
        let copy = self.subdata(in: range)

        print(copy as NSData) // Prints  <02030405>

        return copy.withUnsafeBytes{
            $0.load(fromByteOffset: 0, as: UInt32.self).bigEndian
        }
    }
}

let data = Data(array)
let datadropped = data.dropFirst(2)
print(data as NSData) // Prints <00010203 04050607 08090a0b 0c>
print(datadropped as NSData)   // Prints <02030405 06070809 0a0b0c>


let sub =  data.subdata(in: 4..<8 )  // gives 4,5,6,7
let sub2 = datadropped.subdata(in: 4..<8) // also gives 4,5,6,7

data.uint32(offset: 2)
```

Now if I set the offset in the final line as 0 or 1 it crashes. An offset of 2 works but returns a uint constructed using the bytes 02,03,04,05 which is not what I would expect.  The documentation states the dropFirst() and subdata() return copies of the data.

I did get my uint32 function working with the following code. But I would like to know why the ranges of bytes in the initial function are not working.  How do I force a genuine new copy of the Data?  If someone could explain it to me I'd be grateful.

```
extension Data
    func uint32( offset:Int)-> UInt32{
        let array = Array(0...3).map {
            uint8(offset: $0+ offset)
        }
        return array.withUnsafeBytes{
            $0.load(fromByteOffset: 0, as: UInt32.self).bigEndian
        }
    }

   func uint8( offset:Int)-> UInt8 {
        return self.withUnsafeBytes{
            $0.load(fromByteOffset: offset, as: UInt8.self).bigEndian
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is are extraneous `.` in the code. `data1` is not defined

Comment: Can't reproduce the crash in a playground. subdata to Data is just like ArraySlice to Array

Comment: Thanks , corrected.  I did some manual edits after the copy and missed them. Strange though as they aren't in my playground and I didn't edit those bits.

Comment: Also, it isn't crashing for me now. I think it has something to do with the alignment of the data.  I've been struggling with this all day throughout my codebase.

Comment: Good luck I hope Vadian's answer is of help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datadropped` is a [Slice](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/slice)

It contains the subset of the data but it shares the same indices with the original collection. It crashes because the first index of `datadropped` is 2, not 0.

To get a new `Data` object you have to write

```
let datadropped = Data(data.dropFirst(2))
```

For more information about slices please watch [WWDC 2018: Using Collections Effectively](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/229/) (from 11:00)

Note: You can drop the `fromByteOffset` parameter

```
return copy.withUnsafeBytes{
    $0.load(as: UInt32.self).bigEndian
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I suspected it had something to do with Slices.  However, when I checked the docs it stated     /// Return a new copy of the data in a specified range.
    ///
    /// - parameter range: The range to copy.
    public func subdata(in range: Range<Data.Index>) -> Data.      Is there an easy way to determine if Data is a slice?  I had also wrapped my new data copies in a Data() earlier when trying to avoid alignment issues.  It didn't seem to make a lot of difference.

Comment: Read the documentation. Yes, `subdata` returns a new `Data` object, but the receiver is crucial (`data` or `dataDropped`)

Comment: Ah, I've noticed the problem I think.  dropFirst which I used earlier returns subsequences.  This then would have rippled the problems through my code. Thanks for your help.